# How to reduce IOPS using batch queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, provisioned-iops

I'm trying to figure out the relation between IOPS and the number of queries in AWS RDS.
I have a `Postgresql 10` in `db.t3.medium` size machine. As I understand, it doesn't mean that a select/insert statement always equals an I/O. I couldn't find any documentation for the calculation.

Is it possible to use batch queries to reduce IOPS in RDS? Does AWS RDS have a default I/O block size for the queries?

Comment: It's possible, but high IOPS are far more likely to be the result of queries using uncached data. You can make repeated queries against [pgbuffercache](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgbuffercache.html) to get a sense of buffer churn.

Comment: Do you know how does it affect to IOPS if I batch insert?

Comment: It should reduce the number of writes to the WAL, which must be synced after every transaction. Whether or not that is noticeable depends on how many transactions you're performing currently.